# all Objects change when creating a new array entry

Tags: angular, typescript

when i create a new entry with my form html it get displayed, but when i create a new entry, the entry created before also changes.

position.ts

```
export interface Position{
    
    index:number;
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
    time: string;
}
```

positions.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Positions } from '../mock-positions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-positions',
  templateUrl: './positions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./positions.component.css']
})
export class PositionsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  positionEntrys = 'Positions ';


  positions= Positions;
    

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

create-poistion.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Position } from '../position';
import { Positions } from '../mock-positions';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-position',
  templateUrl: './create-position.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-position.component.css']
})
export class CreatePositionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }



  


  position: Position={
    index: Positions.length,
    lat: -1,
    lng: -1,
    time: "testdata",
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }


  save() : void{
    Positions.push(this.position)
    

   //var postionByTimestamp= Positions.find(x => x.index ==this.position.index);

    //if(postionByTimestamp==null || postionByTimestamp==undefined){
      //Positions.push(this.position)
    //}
    //else{
      //postionByTimestamp=this.position
    //}

    
  }

}
```

when i use the code i commented out, im able to create one object, but cant create another one

my html is a basic form where i can save via a button the form

Comment: It's more difficult to find your error because the logic of manipulation of the data is  done directly in Components. I suggest extracting this logic to a single class, perhaps a service, that you can easily test with testing tools, without having to actually run your app or get into mocking.

Comment: You'll need to show the html and the `mock-positions` file, otherwise we have no idea what this code does.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know for sure how you manipulate the objects but the problem probably comes from these two things. Every time you push a new `position` you will give the index length of `Position[]`. `Positions.length` isn't going to be fixed at a time when you assign it, it's a dynamic value somewhere in memory. A reference to the instance. So all the items before and afterwards will always have the same index because their all pointing to the same instance. You should come up with a way to give unique index (passing a param or simply doing +1 each time).

```js
  position: Position={
    index: Positions.length,
    lat: -1,
    lng: -1,
    time: "testdata",
  }

  save() : void{
    Positions.push(this.position)
```